# Compiler error when using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I using oracle developer tools for viusal studio to develop my pl/sql program,however,I encounter a problem with this simple code
Here is the code

```
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('helloWorld');
END;
```

the debug info as follow:

```
**ERROR
ORA-06550: line 1, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
   <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted SQL string>
The symbol "" was ignored.
ORA-06550: line 2, column 36:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
   begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-id**
```

Comment: can you try just write **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('helloWorld');** and press f9

Comment: Could you copy/paste your code in an editing tool where you can display hidden characters? I suspect you have weird end of line encoding. (line 1 column 6 is the char just after begin, it is not printable)

Comment: Copy/past the code from above sample you gave us and try again. It must work.

Comment: This is the only code in your editor? Or is there more maybe causing problems?

Comment: Yes,This is the only code in my editor.I think is the problem of  oracle developer tools ,the code i pasted above can run on PL/SQL developer.Futher more when i write DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('helloWorld')only without keyword begin and end,the debug info is:
ERROR
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword,i really puzzled

Comment: I haven't used these, but [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18751/building_odt.htm) only seem to talk about querying. But I also don't see where you'd be able to type in your PL/SQL block - in the 'query window'? Can you expand on exactly where and how you're running this? (I'm not sure if some of the comments are assuming this is in SQL Developer, but anyway, clarification might help).

Comment: i run this code using oracle developer tools,a plugin of visual studio,the oracle database server located in 192.168.50.128,the version is 10g

Comment: As you're using a Visual Studio plugin, would it be correct to say that your desktop OS is Windows? And could you tell us what operating system is Oracle running on?

Comment: both visual studio and oracle database are running on windows,i think is the plugin goes wrong.

Comment: The code is working fine without issue. I tried using sqldeveloper. May be you can try sqldeveloper. Its free.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
DECLARE
v_var VARCHAR2(15) := 'helloworld';
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_var);
END;
```